# How to get rid of the "Could not find any member to link for" errors or disable it altogether from Heroku build CLI?

Tags: scala, heroku, compiler-errors, sbt, scaladoc

I'm on Scala 2.12.8 and I use the doc type links `[[]]` everywhere like so e.g.

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

/**  
 * Some class documentation.
 *
 * @param ec the [[ExecutionContext]] instance to default to. 
 */
```

work fine in the IntelliJ IDE but it prevents me from deploying to Heroku when I run the command `sbt stage deployHeroku` because of million errors `Could not find any member to link for` while all the referenced types are well and available ... I get the same million errors when running `sbt doc`

How do you get rid of these doc errors or otherwise, how do you skip doing the `doc` step in the Heroku CLI deployment while running `sbt stage deployHeroku`?